# Problemas Roles multiples Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, backend, symfony4

dentro de mi aplicación quiero que cuando se hace login si esta el usuario activado te envie a una URL y si no esta activado te envie a otra. Lo que no se es como configurar esto en el security, ya que he conseguido hacer bien con un solo role la autentication pero no encuentro ni se me ocurre como hacer esta segunda parte.

Estoy utilizando la extensión de symfony de security y annotations para los path y las entidades.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución:

en el archivo: config/packages/security.yaml usar la configuración default_target_path para ir a una ruta que hará el trabajo de redirigir según el rol.

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                default_target_path: after_login_route_name
```

Luego en el controlador podrías tener algo así:

```
public function afterloginRedirectAction(Request $request)
{

if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_homepage');
    }
    else if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_homepage');
    }
} ...
```

saludos.